# How can I run cron job from the same server where my website is hosted and not from any other platform(other server or browser)?

Tags: php, joomla, cron

I am setting up a cron job on my server to import the news in joomla content from xml file. I want to prevent others from executing the same cron if they knows the cron url. So I need some kind of authentication.
Right now i am using this code for prevention. I know that `empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is always empty if cron is running from server,so this is only for browser prevention

```
//server only access
     if( empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) || empty($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) || ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) ){
            //$_SERVER['argv'] may be  not available when register_argc_argv is disabled.
        if(empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) and (PHP_SAPI === 'cli' || !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) and count($_SERVER['argv']) > 0){

        }else{
            jexit('{"result":"error", "error":"'.JText::_('ACCESS_DENIED').'"}');
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should try console command for cron jobs instead of url

Comment: Maybe some htaccess conf?

Comment: You could move your php script from the public_html folder to any location that is not accessible by public.

Comment: I am not sure about that if I put my script in other folder will it be accessible from cpanel.

Comment: What do you mean "accessible from cpanel"? Accessible by whom? In what way?

Comment: I mean to say that, if I set a cron on server control panel by specifying the url that will call my script, then if that url is called will it able to access the script file being called.